# IFormFile Returns DriveLetter along filename (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core

Im trying to get filename from IFormFile but it returns it with drive letter :

Html Side:

```
<div class="small-4 columns">
   <input type="button" class="button radiusdefined alert" value="Delete" name="deletecontractfile" id="deletecontractfile" style="display:none" />
       </div>
         <div class="small-4 columns">
         <label id="selectedfilename"></label>
       </div>
         <div class="small-4 columns">
         <label for="contractfileraw" class="button">Upload</label>
         <input id="contractfileraw" name="contractfileraw" type="file" class="show-for-sr" />
</div>
```

JS Side :

```
var contractfileraw = $("#contractfileraw");

$("#deletecontractfile").on("click", function () {
    contractfileraw.replaceWith(contractfileraw = contractfileraw.clone(true));
    $('#deletecontractfile').css('display', 'none');
    $("#selectedfilename").text("");
});
$('#contractfileraw').change(function (e) {
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    $("#selectedfilename").text(fileName);
    if(fileName.length > 0){
        $('#deletecontractfile').css('display', 'block');
    }

});
```

and Code-Behind :

```
public int Insert (IFormFile contractfileraw)
        {
                if(contractfileraw.Length > 0)
                {
                    CFile file= new CFile();
                    Stream fileStream = contractfileraw.OpenReadStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        int read;
                        while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                        buffer = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    file.FileType = contractfileraw.ContentType;
                    file.FileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contractfileraw.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    file.FileSize = contractfileraw.Length;
                    file.FileContent = buffer;
```

and the result adds drive path to filename. this happend after update to asp.net core 1.

[image]

Comment: Same thing is happening to me -- but for a time, it wasn't... at least I don't think it was... not sure what changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `System.IO` and call `Path.GetFileName(fileNameHere)`.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

This should work for all browsers and internet/intranet connections.